# Increasing touchable area without increasing icon size

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I increase touchable area of icon without increasing icon size?
I am working on **Ionic 3** project. Especially on iOS UI, the icon size is so small and that's why it's a little bit problem when trying to close the modal.

[image]

Here is the HTML code of **header**:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      About
      <ion-icon name="close" (tap)='closeModal()'></ion-icon>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Trying to increase **height** or **padding** of icon makes some overflow and breaks my UI.

Any suggestions from web designers?

Comment: can you show your code in:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic

Comment: Make a image bigger... the (x) is equal... the image could be bigger.

Comment: You could use the absolute positioning for the close icon and then increase it's padding, your UI should be fine then.

Comment: @theriddle2 Thank you! I set this style and icon's touchable area increased:   ion-title ion-icon{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    right: 0;
  }

Comment: I don't feel like this will be great solution though as you may still find awkward looking button on various device sizes. I would just stick with what framework provides for this use case - use a button instead of icon and leverage icon-only directive there.

Answer (score 0):

It is a better practice to still use "button" element to place a point of interaction for a user (this will increase "touchable area" beyond just icon). To render icon only you can use icon-only attribute:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (tap)='closeModal()'>
          <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Also I recall that Ionic 3 is using hammer.js so you can re-use (click) rather than tap (minor).

If you feel like the cross is too far right - add standard padding-right:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button padding-right ion-button icon-only (click)='closeModal()'>
          <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```